# Как стилизировать первую букву абзаца?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать, чтобы первая буква каждого абзаца была всегда больше обычного текста на +2 и синего цвета?

Answer (score 10):

Для этого не обязательно использовать javascript, можно в css прописать:

> `.someclass:first-letter {font-size: 2em; color: #00f;}`

А дальше в html вот так, к примеру:

> `<p class="someclass">Какой-то небольшой текст</p>`

Comment: Мне не нужны классы...  
На js было бы куда приятнее...

Comment: p:first-letter{font-size:2em;color:#00f}

Comment: "Классы" еще и намного кроссбраузернее. Если с js собрались работать интенсивно, сразу ставьте фаерфокс, оперу, хром, сафари и IETester. Иначе ближе к концу разработки вас будет ждать сюрприз)

Comment: Так вы поможете с скриптом?